# How to -- properly -- underline the ordinal masculine and feminine?

Tags: fontspec, babel, polyglossia, textcomp, fmtcount

There are languages, Portuguese being one of them, where the ordinals (masculine and feminine) are always supposed to be underlined. About half of fonts do not provide underlined-ordinals, leaving up to LaTeX how to address the problem.

There are a few ways that I know of, how to input the ordinals:

1. using plain UTF-8 text:  ª and º
2. commands `\textordmasculine` and `\textordfeminine` from the `textcomp` package
3. using the command `\ordinalnum{}` from the package `fmtcount`

along with some rudimentary stuff like `$10^{\underline{\,\,\text o}}$` and others similar that cannot possible be considered -- proper.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{portuges}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{fmtcount}

\RequirePackage{fontspec}

%\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{TeX Gyre Termes}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\begin{document}
1º = 1\textordmasculine{} = \ordinalnum{1}
2ª = 2\textordfeminine{} = \ordinalnum{2}[f]
\end{document}
```

In all options above the choice is always left to the font at hand and no effort is done to underline it, even if you one uses `Babel` or `Polyglossia` to set the language. And most likely that is not possible to be accomplished in LaTeX, because of the thickness and length of the characters in each font.

It is fairly easy to take a font without underlined-ordinal, like `Times New Roman`, copy just the ordinal characters and built a *companion* font with properly sized and distanced underlining.

Supposed I call this new new two-character font 'TNR Underlined-Numeral Companion'. Is there a way to direct the three types of input above to use the alternate characters in the companion font?

Comment: I already find the superscript ordinal markers horrible; underlining them adds to the ugliness.  I understand that's difficult to go against common usage. In Italian we use Roman numbers for ordinals: when an uppercase I is next to a name, for instance, it is immediately understood to stand for the ordinal; no grammatical gender distinction is needed, because the context is clear. This has advantages and disadvantages: XXIII is a mouthful

Comment: @egreg It is not a question of looks. There are countries where this is the *law* and if you produce documentation without underlining ordinals, you cannot even get an ISO 9000 certification.

Comment: @TeXApprentice A quite interesting question. In Spanish underlining ordinals is currently discouraged and must be replaced by a dot (eg, 23.ª). Do you have a list of countries where underlining is the ‘law’ and/or a more or less official source?

Comment: @JavierBezos I would like to give you a detailed answer, but in this comment space it is next to impossible, so I am going t write an ``answer'' for the question down below. I know only of BR as the place where it is set by law. See below.

Comment: @PauloNey, it's not set by law -- at least not the ordinance (not a law) that you cited. See comment below.

Comment: @TeXApprentice, it is a question of looks. can you please cite the law and the part of the ISO 9000 standard stating that if you are in said country and write a text in said language without underlined ordinal numbers, you won't get the certificate?

Answer (score 4):

I believe that this is a feature left to the font designer who's free to underline the glyph or not.

If your font doesn't have the underline, you can substitute an underlined superscript glyph. In the code below I test for existence of U+0331 COMBINING MACRON BELOW in order to produce a better output; if absent from the current font, underlining is used.

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage{fontspec} % already loaded by polyglossia
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\setmainlanguage{portuges}
%\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{TeX Gyre Termes}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\newunicodechar{º}{\textsuperscript{\ordinalwithunderline{o}}}
\newunicodechar{ª}{\textsuperscript{\ordinalwithunderline{a}}}
\newcommand{\ordinalwithunderline}[1]{%
  \iffontchar\font"0331 #1^^^^0331\else\underline{#1}\fi
}

\begin{document}

1º

2ª

\end{document}
```

If your main font happens to underline the glyphs, just comment out the two `\newunicodechar` lines.

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to make it work with other inputs like the two as well as ``biblatex``?

Comment: The appearance changes according to the font you're using. Some are uglier than others. The best thing would be to find a font that has it (there are several, including EB Garamond).

Comment: @TeXApprentice I guess that you have also to redefine `\toxtordmasculine` and `\textordfeminine`, but an example of how `biblatex` does wrong would be needed. In a new question, please, with all the needed details.

Answer (score 1):

There are good answers already that don’t require you to make a new font, but the question you asked deserves an answer, too.

One way you could do it would be to create a new fork of Nimbus Roman or TeX Gyre Termes with underlined ordinals. This could be made available as a stylistic set, stylistic alternative, character variant, or OpenType language substitution.

In your solution, where you want to create a new companion font, you could do something like this:

```
\usepackage{fontspec, newunicodechar}

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\numerofont{TNR Underlined-Numeral Companion}[Scale=MatchLowercase]

\renewcommand\textordfeminine{{\numerofont ª}}
\renewcommand\textordmasculine{{\numerofont º}}
\newunicodechar{ª}{\textordfeminine}
\newunicodechar{º}{\textordmasculine}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is not an answer to the main question, only an answer for Javier Bezos question above.

It does not surprise me if Brazilians have a law that obliges one to underline the ordinals. They are notorious *paper-pushers* and have laws for everything. As for the Portuguese, it is about the same, we copied many stuff from them.

In the US there is a common cheap-talk that occurs when someone mentions something unordinary:

```
    There is a web-page for that ....
```

In Brazil they say:

```
    There is a law for that ...
```

Several pieces on the net mention that it is law in BR and optional in PT. Examples are: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_indicator) and [Adobe](https://community.adobe.com/t5/type-typography/underlined-masculine-feminine-ordinal-indicators/td-p/2442171?page=1).

Most interesting is the [Manual of Style](https://www12.senado.leg.br/manualdecomunicacao/redacao-e-estilo/estilo/numeros-ordinais) from the Brazilian Senate, on the subject -- it does NOT comply with the supposed law -- most likely because the programmers of the web-site do not know how to do it.

Nonetheless, the fact, if there is a law or not -- it is the *de facto* use in the country, where people are so accustomed to it that for them it feels strange not to have the underline.

These three examples below are from the front-pages of the three largest newspapers in the country, all from today (Oct 31, 2020): [O Globo](https://oglobo.globo.com/), [A Folha](https://www.folha.uol.com.br/) and [O Estadão](https://www.estadao.com.br/).

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here is an extract from the Copyright page of the VOLP - Vocaulário Ortográfico da Língua Portuguesa.

[image]

The number of fonts with underlined numerals is very small, for example, out of the Microsoft basic set only Cambria and Courier have it. This forces Brazilians to look for alternate fonts for almost everything -- like it is the case of both newspapers above. It also fosters a bootleg market for modified fonts and solutions for MS Word, InDesign, web pages, etc ...

I could only emphatically second a proposal of a solution that will solve this problem in a clean way. Ideally we should add 4 new points to Unicode, for "o" and "a" specifically with and without underline, but they seem to be more interested in adding new emojis ... In this way font designers would be free to add it to their design and would be easy to add patches to fonts, etc ...

Comment: These nomenclatures are complete. They are what they are: nomenclatures. It's a list of words attached to certain concepts. "Morphology" is not they way things look, it's not their graphical appearance. Both are "portarias" (ordinance, order, decree), not laws. And the Brazilian one is a recommendation for teaching and exams, whereas the Portuguese one is "in force after a trial period". I have so far found no law regulating the graphical appearance of ordinal numbers, just a habit, but if you come up with one, I'd like to know.

Comment: The Wikipedia page and the Adobe Page don't mention a law at all... did I miss something?

Comment: No, I haven't got it mixed: Brazil: "PORTARIA Nº 36, DE 28 DE JANEIRO DE 1959

Art.1º - **Recomendar** .... Both are "portarias". And "portaria" and "lei" are different things. "Portaria" regulates a law.

Comment: Don't be so pedantic: that's what I meant. They don't mention that it is law, neither Wikipedia nor the Adobe site. Don't dodge, just show me where they "mention that it is law."

Comment: Attain yourself to the facts. "is mandatory" doesn't mean it's a law. Quote [7] means Wikipedia citing Adobe forum, which the guy asking the question say "they are supposed", but provides no source.

Comment: You said "the Brazilian one is indeed a law", having an effect akin to a law or regulating a law isn't the same thing. It's two ordinances about **nomenclatures**, they **are complete**, and say nothing about the appearance of ordinal numerals. See my first comment. They don't relate at all to the graphical appearance of ordinal numbers, **and** morphology isn't the looks of glyphs. That's it.

Comment: How do you know it's a **nomenclature** that is 500 pages long? It's a **complete** legal norm!

Comment: Thank you for the links, but I have found nothing about the rules for ordinals. Actually, there is no need for separate Unicode characters, because a font may contain language dependent variants. We Spaniards are struggling to achieve the opposite – no underlines! I wonder if we can do something at the `luatex` level to ensure each language follows their own “laws” somehow.

Comment: Yes Javier, I believe the Italians, Spaniards and even the Portuguese want the underline off, but they have an advantage because very few fonts have the underline. I did ask the question to Will and he said he sees - no solution - using ``fontspec`` alone... but I think it will be hard to find a solution involving TeX alone because the best thickness and position of the underline will depend on the font.

Comment: Since @PauloNey removed the two ordinances [1](http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/acordo.php?action=ngbras) [2](http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/acordo.php?action=nomenclatura) that were supposed to be "laws frequently quoted" (by whom?) and all his comments, much of my comments don't make much sense anymore. Here they are just for reference. He couldn't get arount the fact that they're not laws, that the Brazilian ordinance/decree is a recommendation, and even came up with the bogus claim that the nomenclatures were 500-pages long. Have you found the "500-page nomenclature" yet?